# Check if polygons intersect in c++

Tags: c++, geospatial

I have two polygons whose minimum and maximum, latitude and longitude are given below:

```
Polygon A: minimum_latitude=2.089 degree, maximum_latitude=2.93 degree, minimum_longitude=-122.95 degree, maximum_longitude=-122.85 degree

Polygon B: minimum_latitude=2.1 degree, maximum_latitude=2.83 degree, minimum_longitude=-121.95 degree, maximum_longitude=-120.85 degree
```

How do I check in c++ whether the Polygon A intersects (or is contained in) Polygon B or not?

My latitude and longitude are in degrees. Do I need to convert them to radians for checking whether the polygons intersect or not?

One way to check intersection is to check whether minimum_latitude of polygon B lies between minimum_latitude and maximum_latitude of polygon A and vice versa? Is this the correct way of checking. Do I need to convert the latitude and longitude to radians for performing the intersection test.

Comment: I can think of polygons which would make the idea you give in last paragraph to solve this not work ;)

Comment: @BitTickler Ok. Then can you please suggest some solution :)

Comment: Isn't that the intersection of two axis aligned rectangles?

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes the intersection is between two axis aligned rectangles

Comment: I think you can use scan line algorithm for that. Sweep line over the space and create list of edges for each polygon along the line. For halfway ordinary polygons (yes, there are also funny ones like self-intersecting polygons), this yields either non intersecting line segments or intersecting line segments, which in turn is easy to handle. [A1;A2; B1;B2] <-> [A1;B1;A2;B2]

Comment: @BitTickler Can I run sweep line algorithm over both degrees and radians. Or do I first need to convert degree to radians before running Sweep line algorithm

Comment: @AlexanderFell Depends on the size of your areas. The first approximation of a sphere near a point is a tangent plane. But the algorithm you use does not decide whether you should use spherical geometry or not. The use case and the size of the areas does. Meaning: It depends on if you only want to test for intersection (bool) or if you want to do something with the resulting intersecting area.

Answer (score 3):

No need for any external libraries etc.

1. Exclude polygons that are NOT intersecting by range checking as Constantin suggested
2. Check any point of poly1 is inside of poly2 by again simple range checking on both directions. If any they are intersecting, if all then it is contained.
3. Control the opposite set of 2
4. Prepare your candidate lines by using results of 2 and 3, then send a ray from a polygon to lines of another polygon. if any hits they are intersecting.

thats it.

This is the simplest and quickest way. If you want several optimizations are possible by using sorted data or octrees etc.

Comment: Would this still work for two polygons who intersect but no point rests inside the other polygon? For example, two rectangles who make a cross shape.

Comment: then you will need line intersections. still above answer will provide quick and proper filtering

Answer (score 2):

You can use the min/max as a quick check if the polygons do NOT intersect; if the bounding rectangles overlap, the enclosed polygons MAY intersect... but you need further checks to be sure.  Unless you are using Polygons to store only simple rectangles ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am using Polygons to store simple rectangles. One more questions: Should I convert degrees to radians before checking for intersection

Comment: As long as everything uses the same units, you are fine.

Comment: Thanks :) At times I also need to expand the polygon by a certain distance d=10 km. So, do you think radians will be more appropriate for expanding polygons?

Comment: radian is a rotation measurement unit..expanding a polygon is translation of some lines of rectangle, so radian or whatever has nothing to do with expanding a polygon.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great [Polygon Collision](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Polygon_Collision) algorithm that may be just what you are looking for:
essentially, you check for the shortest distance between the polygons.